# Check if an HTML object is inside another HTML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an example like this:

```
<div id="President">
  <div id="Congressman">
    <div id="Senator">
      <div id="Major"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way in Javascript or jQuery that we can check if the div 'Major' is a child element of all other divs? Thank you.

Comment: So you have to check if it is a child of them ALL?

Comment: I think in this case we can have a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript [`node.contains(other node)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

```js
var qS = function(v) { return document.querySelector(v); };

console.log(qS('#President').contains(qS('#Major')))
```

```html
<div id="President">
  <div id="Congressman">
    <div id="Senator">
      <div id="Major"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on comment, combining jQuery and plain javascript

```js
console.log( $('#President')[0].contains( $('#Major')[0] ) )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="President">
  <div id="Congressman">
    <div id="Senator">
      <div id="Major"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this right now. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @LanMai Added a sample how to

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your answer worked! Just a small question: If I use var outer = $('#President') it won't work. Can I use $() in this case?

Comment: @LanMai Not like that, as you will mix jQuery with plain javascript ... will add a sample how to

Comment: @LanMai Updated, added a 2:nd sample

Answer (score 2):

Use [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/):

```js
console.log($('#President').has('#Major').length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" 
 integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div id="President">
  <div id="Congressman">
    <div id="Senator">
      <div id="Major"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this right now. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: You mean `$('#President').has('#Major')`

Comment: Thanks for informing. My mistake @blex

Answer (score 2):

Is children of all other divs (using jquery):

`$('#Major').parents('#Senator,#Congressman,#President').length === 3`

Comment: This is the simplest and shortest answer that checks that all divs are parents of `#Major`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to do it but it's a simple one and it works

```
$('#President').find('#Major').length !== 0
```